# Background color for JPEGs while keeping transparency for PNGs with ImageMagick/Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm using [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to resize photos in a Rails app. Some of them are not square pictures, so borders are added. I'd like the PNG pictures to keep a transparent background while the JPEG ones to have a red background.

Using the `-background transparent` option seems to work fine for the PNGs, but adds black borders to the JPGs.

Adding a `-fill red` option [as recommended](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#background) doesn't change much, and only using `-background red` works on the JPEGs but makes the PNG backgrounds red too.

I wonder what I'm missing here. Or is there a way to conditionally pass options depending on the input file format?

The command line I use is:

`convert original.jpg -resize "200x200" -background transparent -fill red -gravity center -extent 200x200 result.jpg`

Comment: What is the exact command you are using for your resizing operation? (the result of `-background transparent` operations are sometimes dependent on the context of other settings)

Comment: `convert original.jpg -resize "200x200" -background transparent -fill red -gravity center -extent 200x200 result.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

I would try to derive a custom processor from `Paperclip::Processor` and have its `make` method modify the settings for each case and then run `super`. Have a look at http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/Paperclip/Processor